# Re-projecting base map (WGS 84 EPSG: 4326)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, spatialite

I am trying to change my base map from the open street plug in to Google Street Map from WGS 84 EPSG: 3857 to WGS 84 EPSG: 4326.

My spatialite polygons (originally mapped on United States) projects into the ocean. 
Is there a way to project the spatialite polygons (mapped in WGS 84 EPSG: 4326 setting) to a the new basemap in WGS 84 EPSG: 4326 setting?

Here is the properties image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Do you really mean "to project the spatialite polygons (mapped in WSG 84 EPSG: 4326 setting) to a the new basemap in WSG 84 EPSG: 4326 setting" - those are both the same coordinate system.

Comment: Hi, Yes I do. My spatialite layer is mapped in EPSG 4326 on a EPSG 3857 base map. This is giving me trouble when I export it into CARTO. The map polygon outlines do not match CARTO's map which is WSG 84 EPSG 4326.

Comment: What is the extent of the polygon layer, as reported by QGIS with right-click om the layer, properties, metadata tab, properties section?

Comment: Even though you used the base map to assist in mapping your polygons, the polygons themselves are independent of the base layer. You can switch to a different base map and the polygons will remain.

Comment: @AndreJ image updated into question

Comment: @csk the main issue i am encountering happens when i transport this shp file into CARTO DB. The polygon does not match the base map there. Which is set to EPSG 4326. Not sure how to work around that other than to change the base map I originally have been working on.

Comment: If you change the base map in QGIS, are the polygons correctly aligned?

Comment: The extent of your polygon layer (as shown in the layer properties) is over the Pacific Ocean, not the United States. My guess is that the original base map you used was incorrectly aligned. If that's the case, all of those polygons are unusable. I hate to say it, but I think you're going to have to start over and re-digitize the polygons with a good base map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spatialite layer looks ok with EPSG:4326 (not sure where you got 144 East, which is outside the US though).

If Carto DB needs coordinates in Web Mercator meters (EPSG:3857), use `Save As ...` to copy the data into a new spatialite database, with CRS set to EPSG:3857. That way you can work on with your original database, or the new one. Both should be on the same spot in QGIS with OTF enabled.

No need to change the basemap CRS in QGIS, or re-digitize all your polygons.

Comment: The dataset includes international cities. But the overall solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use the Quickmapservices plug-in instead of open layers. You will have access to more online layers (including open street maps) and they project correctly no matter your CRS is. Hope it helps. 
In case you use Quickmapservices and your layer is still going into the ocean, the issue will be on the real EPSG of the shp.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already mapped approx 800 polygons onto the spatialite layer to the google street maps layer. I was hoping for a solution to translating these polygons without losing the shape of the outlines. Thank you though, I will use the quickmapservice for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I am using QGIS 2.18. Go to Raster->Projections->Reproject, put your input source, the output name, check the output source and select the projection that you want.

Comment: This does not work for tile-based basemaps from the OpenLayers plugin.